# How can &nbsp; be escaped as &#160; using CKEDITOR 4 config?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have set ckeditor 4 with the following overrides set in config.js for [entity](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html) handling

```
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.entities_additional = '#39,#160';
```

The default for `config.entities_additional` is `'#39'`.

When I use the above configuration, the output encoding breaks - I get several `&undefined;` entities in the output.

Is this a defect in ckeditor?  There appears to be a workaround:

```
config.entities_processNumerical = 'force';
```

but this has the undesirable effect of encoding all non-ascii characters as numerical entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you wanted this to be done with config.js, but if you haven't found a solution, it could be done like this (assuming a CKEDITOR instance named `editor1`):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {              
    evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        text: function(value) {
            return value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '&#160;');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need the entities plugin in your config:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'entities';
```

Comment: It is enabled by default, that's why its properties have some effect for OP.